# Как перейти от типа character к первоначальному типу в R?

Tags: r

Мне нужно ввести с клавиатуры число и проверить является ли оно целым.
Если выводить как `a <- as.numeric(readline())`, то какое не было бы число, оно всегда будет типа **double**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `as.numeric` стоит использовать `as.integer`. В данном случае числа с плавающей точкой будут преобразованы в целые.

```r
> typeof(as.integer(readline()))
11
[1] "integer"
> typeof(as.integer(readline()))
1.1
[1] "integer"
> typeof(as.integer(readline()))
abc
[1] "integer"
Предупреждение:
В typeof(as.integer(readline())) : в результате преобразования созданы NA
```

Если нужно преобразование с проверкой, то есть другие варианты. Приведу два из них:

- `checkmate::asInt`
- `base::scan`

#### `checkmate::asInt`

```r
> checkmate::asInt(1.1)
Ошибка в checkmate::asInt(1.1) :
  Assertion on '1.1' failed: Must be of type 'single integerish value', not 'double'.
> checkmate::asInt(1)
[1] 1
```

#### `base::scan`

```r
> scan(file = stdin(), n = 1, what = integer())
1: asdfasd
1: 
Ошибка в scan(file = stdin(), n = 1, what = integer()) :
  'scan()' ожидает 'an integer', а не 'asdfasd'
> scan(file = stdin(), n = 1, what = integer())
1: 1.1
1: 
Ошибка в scan(file = stdin(), n = 1, what = integer()) :
  'scan()' ожидает 'an integer', а не '1.1'
> scan(file = stdin(), n = 1, what = integer())
1: 100
Read 1 item
[1] 100
```